# Custom element extending from "iframe" disabling access to window.top

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have been trying to integrate a third party web-based tool in my project using an iframe. Unfortunately, the third party application makes an extensive use of `window.top.whatever` and is hosted in a different domain so it just won't work.
I planned on using a custom element extending from an iframe, rebasing the window.top to use the iframe's window instead of the top one. That's OK because it is supposed to work only in Chrome. The thing is that I only made the simplest implementation of an extended iframe element like so:

```
<script>
var RebaseIframe = document.registerElement('rebase-iframe', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLIframeElement.prototype),
  extends: 'iframe'
});
</script>

<iframe is="rebase-iframe" src="https://third-party-app.fake">
```

And with only this, it worked! The third party application treats window.top as its own window which is exactly what I wanted.
But I've done nothing, which is kinda confusing. Anyone can tell me wheter this is a bug or an expected behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've too did small tests and indeed usually window's top is owning window unless it's the topmost one! Therefore standard iframe's behavior looks right and of an extended one - wrong. Do you have any additional insights on this?

Comment: I do not. Sorry